# When to use a tag, and when not to use a tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags, edits

I just answered this question on SO: [Converting associative POST data input into a serialized array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822595/561731)

I just noticed that someone basically shaved off all the tags except [php](/questions/tagged/php), all of the tags that were there seemed let.

The user's reasoning for shaving the tags:

> That's not what tags are for.

**Then What are they for??**

If one cannot tag their question with all the relevant tags to it, what are the tags there for?

[Link to the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6822595/revisions)

Comment: I personally think those were ok. Granted, you don't want to always put all the words of the title in the tags (which I think was Dan's point there) but in this case I think that was ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I think that this user has got it wrong, tags are for categorising questions.

It may well be that the OP chose the wrong tags, but then they should be replaced by better ones. It also may well be that the OP added too many tags - you don't have to use all the available slots in every question (unless they are all relevant of course), but I can't think that just leaving [php](/questions/tagged/php) is constructive in this case.

Comment: i have seen this in many places, not just this question. Why cant one fill up all the tag places? if they all are relevant, why not?

Comment: @Neal - you can if they are all relevant, however you don't *have* to.

Comment: How do you two feel about in this case was Neal in his place to revert the edit? I feel in this case a revert was not inappropriate.

Comment: @Chris -- true, but if the OP put them there (even if the OP might have much lower rep then you) that does not give someone the `right` (idk if that is the right word to use) to retag and **remove** the relevant ones, and once in a blue moon **add** tags that have nothing to do with the OP

Comment: @Neal - I thought my answer stated that *in this case* the edit was over the top. You are right, an edit should not remove relevant tags.

Answer (score 8):

You should tag your question from the perspective of keyword search, in my opinion.  From that perspective, the `input` is immaterial - it's unlikely that a person searching using the `input` keyword would care about your question as it's not about inputs, but rather serializing arrays.  `Multidimensional-array` is at best redundant and at worst misleading; your array isn't a multidimensional array, it's a standard associative array.  For my money, it should be tagged `php`, `array`, and `serialization`.

Answer (score 1):

Tags are for categorizing the questions, but a single tag is normally not sufficient; if it were so, there would be many questions tagged only [php](/questions/tagged/php), and it would be difficult to distinguish between different questions.
All the tags used by the OP were already existing tags and, apart [multidimensional-array](/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array), were also correct. I don't see any reason to remove them.

When I asked a question about which tags to use, I have been told to use the tags that allow the question to reach who can answer it. That doesn't mean to tag [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) a question that is for PHP. It also means to prioritize the used tags; for example, if the question is only marginally related to arrays, then [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) should not be used, or it should be the last tag you add, and only if there aren't other tags that better suit the question.